# Simplify MongoEngine QuerySet Results

Tags: python, mongoengine

## The Problem

I have an API that returns mongoengine results in JSON format, but the frontend (outside of my scope) is unhappy with the format, namely that values like `{"$oid": "60e4a07097ddf1e20fbaaaa0"}` exist.

Here's an example response from hitting a GET endpoint:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Double R Diner",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "user": {
          "$oid": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e519"
        },
        "role": {
          "name": "admin",
          "description": "account creator"
        }
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "$oid": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e516"
        },
        "role": {
          "name": "admin",
          "description": "Double R Diner admin"
        }
      }
    ],
    "buildings": [
      {
        "$oid": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e51e"
      }
    ],
    "address": {
      "country": "United States",
      "province_state": "WA",
      "city": "Twin Peaks"
    },
    "main_contact": {
      "$oid": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e519"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e520"
    }
  }
]
```

The nesting of `$oid` fields is where the problem lies, as the frontend considers this an over-complication that locks us into this weird mongoengine format standard. This nesting should be removed, with the `$oid` string values replacing their nesting dict where possible. As you can see, nesting can occur within dicts (`main_contact`) and/or lists (`buildings`).

The desired outcome looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Double R Diner",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "user": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e519",
        "role": {
          "name": "admin",
          "description": "account creator"
        }
      },
      {
        "user": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e516",
        "role": {
          "name": "admin",
          "description": "Double R Diner admin"
        }
      }
    ],
    "buildings": [
      "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e51e"
    ],
    "address": {
      "country": "United States",
      "province_state": "WA",
      "city": "Twin Peaks"
    },
    "main_contact": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e519",
    "_id": "60de35e078ba4f6f3f41e520"
  }
]
```

I think this is a recursion problem, and recursion breaks my brain.

## The Question

How can I best achieve the above transformation; simplifying the response data structure and allowing the front end to be unaware of mongoengine `$oid` dicts regardless of how deeply nested these ObjectIds are?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this, but I seem to have solved this problem with the following implementation:

```py
def simplify_ids(obj):
    if type(obj) not in [list, dict]:
        return obj

    if type(obj) == dict:
        if len(obj) == 1 and '$oid' in obj.keys():
            obj = obj['$oid']
            return obj
        else:
            for key, value in obj.items():
                obj[key] = simplify_ids(value)

    elif type(obj) == list:
        for index, nested_obj in enumerate(obj):
            obj[index] = simplify_ids(nested_obj)

    return obj


def clean_query_results(query_results):
    if type(query_results) != QuerySet:
        raise TypeError(f'Input must be a mongoengine QuerySet, not {type(query_results)}')
    result_string = query_results.to_json()
    loaded = json.loads(result_string)  # List
    cleaned = list()
    for obj in loaded:
        cleaned.append(simplify_ids(obj))
    return json.dumps(cleaned)
```

The calling endpoint needs only to change the Response line from:

```py
return Response(query_results.to_json(), mimetype='application/json', status=200)
```

to:

```py
return Response(clean_query_results(query_results), mimetype='application/json', status=200)
```